# Using preg_replace to make ordinals appear in all lower case

Tags: php, string, case-sensitive

I have a column of address data that has ordinals displayed like this:

**3Rd Floor, Cumbrian House**

**Room 223, 2Nd Floor**

when I would like them to be displayed like this instead:

**3rd Floor, Cumbrian House**

**Room 223, 2nd Floor**

I'm trying to make use of the preg_replace function to swap out a capitalised letter, that directly follows a number, with a lower case letter instead. (I admit this is my first time using the preg_replace function. I am however fine with preg_match and regular expressions).

So far I have:

```
$string = '3Rd Floor, Cumbrian House';

$ordinalregex = '/(^.*\d+)([A-Z])/';
$correctordinal = '$1'.strtolower('$2');

echo preg_replace($ordinalregex,$correctordinal,$string)."<br>";
```

But its not having the desired effect and outputs the line exactly as it first appeared.

Thanks

Comment: The input string definition(s) is/are missing in your example code. Also the code looks a bit much for the case you outline. Please reduce it to a minimum example, e.g. rewrite it from scratch isolating the sole issue.

Comment: Also why can't you use `strtr` and replace `3Rd` with `3rd` and `2Nd` with `2nd`?

Comment: @hakre Because I need a catch all solution so I don't have to write case by case replacements when an address has 4th, 9th, etc... It should also be able to deal with flat addresses so 239A becomes 239a.

Comment: Well, could it be some wrong method has been applied on the data before-hand? It might be a little late, but it's best when you prevent that in the first place. For that, it's often helpful to know about look-around: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as I'm not sure you can replace based on the part you matches in normal preg_replace. What you need to do is use a callback function that takes the matches array and processes it (you could also just use preg_match and then work with the matches seperetaly).

This example works (although it uses an anonymous function for the callback, which requires PHP 5.3.0+):

```
function fixOrdinals($string) { 
    return preg_replace_callback("/[0-9][A-Z]/",
        function ($matches) { 
            return strtolower($matches[0]);
        },
        $string
    );
}

echo fixOrdinals("3Rd Floor, Cumbrian House")."\n";
echo fixOrdinals("Room 223, 2Nd Floor")."\n";
echo fixOrdinals("4Th Room, 2Nd Floor")."\n";
```

**Output:**

```
3rd Floor, Cumbrian House
Room 223, 2nd Floor
4th Room, 2nd Floor
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution to me. I've not come across the concept of a $matches array before or anonymous functions for that matter but I can see what they're doing and apply the same principles to other address anomalies like 'O'Reilly' staying as O'Reilly whilst 'St John'S' should be St John's. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $ordinalregex = '/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/ei';
    $input = "Room 223, 2Nd Floor";

    $input = preg_replace($ordinalregex, "strtolower('$1$2')", $input);

    print($input);
```

The /e modifier tells the interpreter to use eval. Now this works, however it's NOT SECURE. If your input has a \0 (null char) due to a C bug the interpreter will execute the part of the sting after the \0.

Comment: The /e modifier was deprecated in PHP 5.5, probably due to it not being secure. preg_replace_callback is the recommended method now.

Comment: @lePunk - even on earlier versions, the `e` modifier is still considered bad practice. `preg_replace_callback()` has been available since 5.0.